# Error al mostrar datos en handlebars-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, handlebars.js

Estoy tratando de acceder al id de este elemento enviado por json en handlebars.js

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "message": {
        "message":"sdasdasasd",
        "type":"photo",
        "post_id":55,
        "title":"",
        "description":"",
        "url":"",
        "image":"",
        "code":"",
        "provider":"",
        "photo": {
           "http:\/\/timeline.dev\/storage\/app\/public\/vdjkelly\/timeline_SzfkoDzMWc.jpg":"http:\/\/timeline.dev\/storage\/app\/public\/vdjkelly\/timeline_SzfkoDzMWc.jpg",
           "http:\/\/timeline.dev\/storage\/app\/public\/vdjkelly\/timeline_qm7sq7RY1K.jpg":"http:\/\/timeline.dev\/storage\/app\/public\/vdjkelly\/timeline_qm7sq7RY1K.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

El código que tengo así

```
@{{#each photo}}

  <li class="grid">
    <div class="posted-photo">
      <div class="photo">
        <div class="fphoto-item">
          <a class="ShowStatus" data-id="@{{post_id}}" href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox@{{post_id}}">
            <img src="@{{this}}" class="imgpreview" id="@{{post_id}}" rel="@{{post_id}}">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>
@{{/each}}
```

y aun así no me accede al `post_id`

El código de mi js es el siguiente:

```
var template = render_template('#send-photo', {
    'message': response.message.message, 
    'type': response.message.type, 
    'photo': response.message.photo, 
    'post_id': response.message.post_id
});
```

Comment: te muestra algun dato? Has utilizado <script type="text/x-handlebars-template"> ?

Comment: Si las fotos me las muestra, y si lo estoy usando

Comment: podrías poner el HTML generado?

Comment: Interesante JSON, ¿por qué repetir la fuente en el identificador y el valor en lugar de usar algo como "src"? Aparte de eso, en el HTML generado, ¿data-id = undefined?

Comment: <div class="fphoto-item">
              <a class="ShowStatus" data-id="" href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox">
                <img src="http://timeline.dev/storage/app/public/vdjkelly/timeline_z07ytXxVDD.jpg" class="imgpreview" id="" rel="">
              </a>
            </div>

Comment: en data-id="" deberia ir el id @{{post_id}} pero no muestra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Causa: diferentes contextos

El problema sucede porque has cambiado el contexto y entonces `post_id` ya no está accesible.

El concepto de contexto en Handlebars/Mustache sería el objeto cuyas propiedades puedes acceder usando las llaves `{{ }}` en un momento dado. El nivel superior del contexto es el objeto que has pasado como segundo parámetro en `render_template`, pero *helpers* como `#each` lo modifican.

Al hacer `@{{#each photo}}` estás cambiando el contexto del original a exclusivamente el objeto `photo` donde ya no hay una propiedad llamada `post_id` por lo que `{{post_id}}` se muestra vacío.

Para más información sobre contextos y paths en la [documentación de Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) (en inglés).

## Solución: cambiar ruta con `../`

En tu caso has cambiado el contexto a `photo`, por lo que sólo quieres subir al contexto del padre. Para ello puedes usar `../` para cambiar la ruta/path de la propiedad a la del padre. En tu caso, lo que tendrías que cambiar es `{{post_id}}` por `{{../post_id}}` y eso solucionará el problema.

> Nota: `../` puede combinarse para seguir atravesando los contextos. `../` accederá al padre, pero puedes "subir" más contextos: `../../` permitirá acceder a una propiedad en el padre del padre, `../../../` para el contexto del padre del padre del padre, y así sucesivamente.

Las líneas que necesitarían cambios en tu código:

```
<a class="ShowStatus" data-id="@{{../post_id}}" href="#" data-lightbox="lightbox@{{../post_id}}">
    <img src="@{{this}}" class="imgpreview" id="@{{../post_id}}" rel="@{{../post_id}}">
</a>
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución.. me sirve de mucho tu explicación esta clara y entendible se le agradece.